# Running method on tkinter scale and setting it label

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

master.geometry("300x100")

master.title("Convert Scale To Farenheight")


def convertToFarenheight(f):
f=int(f)
f=f*9/5+32   ## convert toFarenheight 

var = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=var).pack()
  y=Scale(master,from_=-100,to=100,variable=var,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=convertToFarenheight)
y.pack()

mainloop()
```

My issue is i'm trying to change the text label to calculated value by my method run on the scale method. I'm not sure what to change in my method to get it to work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some serious problem in your indentation.

I think this is what you are trying:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("300x100")
master.title("Convert Scale To Farenheight")


def convertToFarenheight(var):
    f1= int(var)
    f2.set(f1*9/5+32)

f2=IntVar()
x=Label(master,textvariable=f2)
x.pack()

var = StringVar()
y=Scale(master,from_=-100,to=100,variable=var,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=convertToFarenheight)
y.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I would like add a text label as well to identify the number. Is there like a attribute for that? Also any good sites you recommend for learning more on tkinter? Thanks

Comment: x **is** a text Label. You could learn from [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) or [NewMexicoTech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)